# Using linq to grab data from my xml c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I want to use linq to grab data from my xml document (I can't change this XML due to it being generated from an outside program). For some reason `_dup_check_lvl` and `_inv_doc_type` are null.

## code

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Text; 
using System.Threading.Tasks; 
using System.Data.SqlClient; 
using System.Xml.Linq; 

namespace ETrans 
{ 
    public class Edata 
    { 


        List<Edata> invoice = new List<Edata>(); 

        public string _dup_check_lvl { get; private set; } 

        public string _inv_doc_type { get; private set; } 





        public void get_invoice_data() 
        { 
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml"); 
            var invoice_data = doc.Root 
                                .Elements("Invoice") 
                                .Select(x => new Edata 
                                { 
                                    _inv_doc_type = (string)x.Attribute("Check_Level").Value, 
                                    _dup_check_lvl = (string)x.Attribute("Document_Type").Value 
                                }) 
                                .ToList(); 


            Console.WriteLine(_dup_check_lvl); 
            Console.WriteLine(_inv_doc_type); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

## my xml doc

```
<Invoice> 
  <Check_Level>2</Check_Level> 
  <Document_Type>RE</Document_Type> 
<Invoice>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work better:

```
var invoice_data = doc.Elements("Invoice")
                     .Select(x => new Edata  
                     {
                         _inv_doc_type = x.Element("Check_Level").Value,
                         _dup_check_lvl = x.Element("Document_Type").Value
                     })
                     .ToList();
```

`Document_Type` and `Check_Level` are elements, not attributes.  Also, this assumes that the file will have multiple `Invoice` elements, which would violate XML form.

So, considering that an XML file can have only one top-level element, what you really want to probably something like this:

```
void Main()
{
    var edata = new Edata();
    edata.get_invoice_data();

    Console.WriteLine(edata._dup_check_lvl);
    Console.WriteLine(edata._inv_doc_type);
}


class Edata
{
    public string _inv_doc_type { get; set; }
    public string _dup_check_lvl { get; set; }

    public void get_invoice_data()
    {
         // replace with reading from file.
        var doc = XDocument.Parse(@"<Invoice> 
      <Check_Level> 2 </Check_Level>
      <Document_Type> RE </Document_Type>
    </Invoice> ");


        var invoice_data = doc.Root;    // or doc.Element("Invoice")

        _inv_doc_type = invoice_data.Element("Check_Level").Value;
        _dup_check_lvl = invoice_data.Element("Document_Type").Value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't do what you think it does.

```
.Select(x => new Edata 
{ 
    _inv_doc_type = (string)x.Attribute("Check_Level").Value, 
    _dup_check_lvl = (string)x.Attribute("Document_Type").Value 
})
```

Instead of setting `_inv_doc_type` and `_dup_check_lvl` on the current instance of `Edata`, it creates and returns a new, different, distinct `Edata` object.

For each "Invoice" element you find in the XML, it creates and returns one `Edata` instance. The Linq returns an enumeration of all those `Edata` objects (thought as it happens, your file creates only one). Then you call `ToList()` on that enumeration to convert it into a `List<Edata>`. That last step isn't strictly necessary.

Try this:

```
public void get_invoice_data() 
{ 
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml"); 

    var invoice_data = 
        doc.Root 
        .Elements("Invoice") 
        .Select(x => new Edata 
        { 
            _inv_doc_type = (string)x.Attribute("Check_Level").Value, 
            _dup_check_lvl = (string)x.Attribute("Document_Type").Value 
        }) 
        ; 

    foreach (var edata in invoice_data) {
        Console.WriteLine(edata._dup_check_lvl); 
        Console.WriteLine(edata._inv_doc_type); 
    }
}
```

If you can guarantee that the XML will *always* contain at most one "Invoice", and you want your current instance of `Edata` to set its own fields from that single "Invoice", this would do:

```
if (invoice_data.Any()) {
    _dup_check_lvl = invoice_data.First()._dup_check_lvl;
    _inv_doc_type = invoice_data.First()._inv_doc_type;
}
```

Comment: Awesome thank you for pointing me in the correct direction! @Ed Plunkett